# Statically linking ffmpeg-sys on Amazon Linux fails with undefined references

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My project depends on the `ffmpeg-sys` crate which is configured to build statically, as follows:

```
[dependencies.ffmpeg-sys]
version = "3.4.1"
default-features = false
features = ["avcodec", "avformat", "swresample", "build", "static"]
```

My project consists of a single simple file:

```
extern crate ffmpeg_sys;

use ffmpeg_sys::av_register_all;

fn main() {
    unsafe { av_register_all() };
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

When compiling with `cargo build` I get the following error:

> Compiling sample v0.1.0 (file:///home/ec2-user/sample)
>   error: linking with 'cc' failed: exit code: 1   |   = note: "cc"
>   "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L"
>
> [... elided for clarity ...]
>
> In function 'sample::main::hbbb19855251826d6':
>             /home/ec2-user/sample/src/main.rs:6: undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
>             collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The required static libraries, `libavformat.a` and friends, are found in the `target/build/debug` folder, showing that `ffmpeg-sys` successfully compiled the libraries.

Here's the `rustc` command that is failing:

> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully: 'rustc --crate-name
>   sample src/main.rs --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C
>   debuginfo=2 -C metadata=250bf40eb277d05a -C
>   extra-filename=-250bf40eb277d05a --out-dir
>   /home/ec2-user/sample/target/debug/deps -C
>   incremental=/home/ec2-user/sample/target/debug/incremental -L
>   dependency=/home/ec2-user/sample/target/debug/deps --extern
>   ffmpeg_sys=/home/ec2-user/sample/target/debug/deps/libffmpeg_sys-fa3ff87f80f2d27e.rlib
>   -L native=/home/ec2-user/sample/target/debug/build/ffmpeg-sys-0b3c813f29a9a20e/out/dist/lib'
>   (exit code: 1)

`libffmpeg_sys-fa3ff87f80f2d27e.rlib` is 207M and I assume therefore contains all the statically compiled ffmpeg code.

This only happens when I build on an Amazon Linux instance. Compiling on my regular Fedora 28 desktop results in a working binary.

How would I go about figuring out the root cause of this error?

Comment: Compare the outputs of build.rs and see the differences. It is located at `target/debug/build/<pkg>/output`

Comment: "This only happens when I build on an Amazon Linux instance." have you check that the version of the linked library are the same ? (not crate version)

Comment: The output of build.rs looks identical. The versions of the linked libraries are the same, they are retrieved from `git` by cargo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by building `llvm` 6.0.1 and then rebuilding with `LIBCLANG_PATH` set to point to the newer version.

It would appear that `rustc` has a minimum version requirement on `libclang.so`, but I could not find an official source documenting that. The version installed on `amazon-linux` is 3.6.2 which is evidently too old.

Comment: *rustc has a minimum version requirement on libclang.so* — it does not. However, ffmpeg-sys uses bindgen, which *does* require clang to parse the C code.

Comment: The error isn't coming from bindgen though, it is a rustc command that is failing.

Comment: yes, compilers like `rustc` report errors about the code you are compiling, I'm not sure what your point is. In this case, you are compiling a build script that links to bindgen which links to libclang. The compiler reports an error because libclang is not present. If the compiler depended on a library that wasn't present, it wouldn't even  *start*.

Comment: libclang was present, it just wasn't new enough. The error message doesn't mention libclang at all, only a missing symbol from ffmpeg.